# Uma expressão portuguesa para a expressão «question à tiroirs»?

Tags: sinônimos, expressões-equivalentes

Existe alguma expressão portuguesa para uma pergunta «entrelaçada»? i.e., para uma pergunta complexa sucedente e conexa com uma anterior, ou até mesmo com posteriores?

Esta questão advém de uma leitura de um texto francês, na qual me deparei com a expressão «question à tiroirs». Não encontrei nenhuma tradução directa, e um dicionário inglês remeteu-me para a expressão «interwoven».

Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda.

Comment: Em inglês seria *interwoven*?

Comment: @bfavaretto sim. Em francês há quem utilize a expressão « question à tiroirs» se não me engano...

Comment: linked question? Sería, no caso, uma pergunta ligada (a outra).

Comment: eu achei isso aqui -> https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/question-%C3%A0-tiroirs.2291650/. Uma das possíveis traduções para o inglês seria **instalment question**. Que traduzindo para o português, seria questão parcelada ou em questão em parcelas. Mesmo assim, não dá a ideia desse aumento de complexidade.

Comment: uma tradução do termo em francês *à tiroir*. Em inglês, poderia ser multi-level. Em português, multi-nível. Uma alternativa é questões relacionadas em multi-nível, ou questões em multi-nível. Uma outra alternativa para inglês seria **compartmentalised** que em português compartimentada. O compartimentada tem o mesmo sentido do **tiroirs** (em gavetas). Não dá essa ideia de aumento de complexidade. Há a possibilidade de ser **modular** em inglês. Cada módulo, fica mais complexo. Então  "pergunta modulada".
https://www.proz.com/kudoz/french_to_english/human_resources/2344088-%C3%A0_tiroirs.html

Comment: @Peixoto obrigado pelos comentários ;)

Comment: @An old man in the sea Sería possível responder à minha pergunta? Entrelaçar descreve relações topológicas, as que existem entre vários nós. Esse francês à tiroir nada tem a ver com a ideia de entrelaçada. Dizemos em inglês: these questions are linked. Isso em português sería: essas perguntas estão [inter] ligadas [entre si].

Comment: Também se fala em perguntas em cascata hierarquizadas.

Comment: @Lambie relações topológicas? Num sentido matemático, ou geofísico? És capaz de ter razão quanto à correcção da minha pergunta. Vou editar.

Comment: @Lambie Foi numa leitura de um texto em francês. Pus mais informação na questão editada. ;)

Comment: Finalmente, deu para entender. Mudei a minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O termo mais gerérico que eu usaria seria **pergunta relacionada**.

Significado de relacionado:

> re·la·ci·o·nar - Conjugar
>
> (latim relatio, -onis + -ar)
>
> verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Fazer uma relação de, meter em lista.
> 2. Referir; narrar; contar.
> 3. Estabelecer relação ou analogia entre; comparar.
>
> verbo pronominal
>
> 4. Adquirir relações.
> 5. Entrar na intimidade de.

Fonte: [Dicionário Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/relacionado)

Buscando a tradução de *à tiroir* em inglês segundo esse [forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/question-%C3%A0-tiroirs.2291650/) seria *instalment question* ou em português, questões parceladas. Porém, não vejo ainda a idéia de aumento de complexidade.

> Merci à vous deux. J'avais pensé à "instalment question" ou à
>   "questions with episodes" mais d'après la réponse d'Embonpoint, c'est
>   une cause perdue.

Pesquisando mais a tradução para o inglês (já que não encontrei muito para o português), encontrei esse [forum](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/french_to_english/human_resources/2344088-%C3%A0_tiroirs.html). Há algumas possibilidades, entre elas: multi-nível e modular.

> French term or phrase:    à tiroirs
>
> English translation:  modular
>
> Hi
>
> Again about training sales staff:
>
> "Une formation à tiroirs par niveaux et adaptable à différents
>   audiences"
>
> My first though was "multi-level" but that would make it "multi-level"
>   for different levels. I think I'm on the right track but can't phrase
>   it.

Com todas essas informações e levando em conta a idéia que *à tiroirs* em francês tem de aumento de complexidade, seria também possível utilizar o termo **pergunta modular** ou **pergunta modulada**.

Comment: Peixoto, editei a minha questão, pois apercebi-me que faltava uma característica essencial, a de complexidade. É uma questão relacionada/interligada a outras mas em que essa relação aumenta a complexidade da mesma.

Comment: De onde vem a sua ideia de "entrelaçada"? Isso parece ser topologia.

Comment: Peixoto, se adicionares a info dos teus comentários, aceito a tua resposta. ;)

Comment: foi bem legal fazer a pesquisa, já que estou também estudando francês.

Answer (score 0):

**Des questions entrelaçées** em francês sería em português: questões interligadas ou assuntos interligados.

En inglês, se diría: inter-related issues or questions.

Agora, faz sentido para mim.

question à tiroir: uma pergunta que suggere outra.

Answer (score 0):

Ex: Isto não é tão simples, esses assuntos são entrelaçados.
Ou, essas pessoas estão entrelaçadas (porém aqui vai depender se é amorosamente, ou por estarem envolvidas em algo que deixe as duas conectadas entre si)